# Select just repeating nodes name

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Consider you have the following xml content, so i need the xpath expression that return just the nodes that repeats itself

```
<A1>
    <NAME>A</NAME>
    <QTY>1</QTY>
</A1>
<A1>
    <NAME>A</NAME>
    <QTY>2</QTY>
</A1>
<A2>
    <NAME>B</NAME>
    <QTY>3</QTY>
</A2>
<A1>
    <NAME>A</NAME>
    <QTY>5</QTY>
</A1>
<A2>
    <NAME>b</NAME>
    <QTY>8</QTY>
</A2>
<A3>
    <NAME>b</NAME>
    <QTY>8</QTY>
</A3>
```

The disire output is something like this:
A1
A2

Comment: Any attempts to solve issue by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()"/>
        <xsl:if
            test="count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = $name]) = 0 and count(following-sibling::*[name() = $name]) != 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: It doesnt the problem, because its brings the following

Comment: A 1  A 2  B 3  A 5  b 8  b 8, but what i want is just the repeatable tag name

Comment: Please, if someone can help

Comment: @AntonioGoncalves Answer Updated

Answer (score 0):

Find nodes such that there is preceding sibling whith the same name

```
//*[name() = preceding-sibling::*/name()]
```

To avoid dublicates in the output you can add an condition that thare is no such following sibling

```
//*[name() = preceding-sibling::*/name()][not(name() = following-sibling::*/name())]
```